# Replace line with multiple trailing patterns

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have 2 files called **myfile.txt** & **responsefile.txt** as below.

**myfile.txt**

```
user=myname
Was_WAS_AdminId=CN=wsadmin,OU=service,OU=WAS_Secure,OU=tb,ou=dcdc,ou=sysadm,dc=info,dc=prd,dc=dcdc
```

**responsefile.txt**

```
'#'Please fill the user id details.
'#'Here is example user=urname.
user=
'#'Please fill the details.
'#'Here is example Was_WAS_AdminId=CN=wsadmin-xxxx.
Was_WAS_AdminId=
```

Now, using above two files want to have the following end result after replacing the matching patterns. The responsefile.txt content should be intact just the matched pattern should be prefixed with details provided in myfile.txt or only replace the whole matching line as 1st pattern are same in both the files and would be more than 100 patterns. SO, please suggest with a simple solution.

**responsefile.txt (new file replaced/substituted with patterns)**

```
'#'Please fill the user id details.
'#'Here is example user=urname.
user=myname
'#'Please fill the details.
'#'Here is example Was_WAS_AdminId=CN=wsadmin-xxxx.
Was_WAS_AdminId=CN=wsadmin,OU=service,OU=WAS_Secure,OU=tb,ou=dcdc,ou=sysadm,dc=info,dc=prd,dc=dcdc
```

Patterns would be same in both the files for example "`user=`" or "`Was_WAS_AdminId=`" in both the files.

Comment: tried         awk -F '=' 'FNR == NR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an awk one liner:

```
$ awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{$0=a[$1]}1' myfile.txt responsefile.txt 
'#'Please fill the user id details.
'#'Here is example user=urname.
user=myname
'#'Please fill the details.
'#'Here is example Was_WAS_AdminId=CN=wsadmin-xxxx.
Was_WAS_AdminId=CN=wsadmin,OU=service,OU=WAS_Secure,OU=tb,ou=dcdc,ou=sysadm,dc=info,dc=prd,dc=dcdc
```

The order of the two files in the command is important

Comment: hi sputnick, the above file is not updating in same file.

Comment: @user2692634 No it doesn't. But you can do `awk ..... > tmp && mv tmp responsefile.txt` to update your file

Answer (score 2):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F'=' 'FNR==NR{i=index($0, "="); a[substr($0, 1, i-1)]=substr($0, i+1);next} ($1 in a) {$0=$0 a[$1]}1' myfile.txt responsefile.txt

'#'Please fill the user id details.
'#'Here is example user=urname.
user=myname
'#'Please fill the details.
'#'Here is example Was_WAS_AdminId=CN=wsadmin-xxxx.
Was_WAS_AdminId=CN=wsadmin,OU=service,OU=WAS_Secure,OU=tb,ou=dcdc,ou=sysadm,dc=info,dc=prd,dc=dcdc
```

Comment: hi Anubhava, the above file is not updating in same file that is responsefile.txt.